# How do i loop and collect data after closing webdrivers

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to be able to go to a tournament href, input that into the url then cycle through the rounds before closing that driver and opening a new one to do the same thing. For some reason i can't figure where to put the beginning url.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()

ytournaments = ['/dpworld-tour/abu-dhabi-hsbc-championship-2021/']

roundids = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for tournamentid in ytournaments:
    
    for roundid in roundids:
        
        page = driver.get(f"https://www.europeantour.com{ytournaments}leaderboard?holebyhole=true&round={roundid}")
        time.sleep(5)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        
        Tour = 'European Tour'
        Year = '2021'
        
        tournamentm = soup.find('h1', class_='event-hero__title').text
        tournament = tournamentm.strip()
        
        coursem = soup.find('p', class_='event-hero__location').text
        course = coursem.strip()
        
        datem = soup.find('p', class_='event-hero__date').text
        date = datem.strip()
        
        dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
        df = dfs[0]
        ndf = np.squeeze(dfs)
        data = pd.DataFrame(ndf)
        
        data["tournament"] = tournament
        data["course"] = course
        data["date"] = date
        data["roundid"] = roundid
        data["Tour"] = Tour
        data["Year"] = Year
        
        filename = f'{tournament}_{roundid}_{Year}.csv'
        data.to_csv(filename)

    driver.quit()
    
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to `.quit()` the `driver` with every iteration, cause you are changing its target url.

Main issue should be to construct the correct `url`, so change `{ytournaments}`:

```
page = driver.get(f"https://www.europeantour.com{ytournaments}leaderboard?holebyhole=true&round={roundid}")
```

to `{tournamentid}`

```
page = driver.get(f"https://www.europeantour.com{tournamentid}leaderboard?holebyhole=true&round={roundid}")
```

Comment: you are right, i put the wrong one in there. I keep flipping those. Geesh! Thank for pointing that out for me!